# How does Magento 2.1.x remove item from cart?

Tags: magento-2.1

In Magento 2.1.8, for minicart, inside Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html around line 96, there's a chunk of code which shows the 'Remove' button.

```
            <div class="secondary">
                <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                   class="action delete">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

But, it's not clear how this button sends data to the controller to delete selected item.

Could someone explain this knockout please?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Magento` remove the Item from the cart by using `sidebar.js` which you can find from,

`vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js`

In this js file below code is responsible to remove the Item from cart,

```
  events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                confirm({
                    content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                    actions: {
                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        confirm: function () {
                            self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                        },

                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        always: function (e) {
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
```

After confirm message, It will call the

```
   _removeItem: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            this._ajax(this.options.url.remove, {
                'item_id': itemId
            }, elem, this._removeItemAfter);
        },
```

It find the Item id as argument and send `AJAX` request to remove the Item from the cart. To remove the Item below controller is responsible,

`vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem.php`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Just to confirm that 
`vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js` is called inside `minicart.js` as js component?